# Python sequence translation

Tags: python, sequence

I have a list of tuples like `[(0, 34), (1, 77), (2, 6), (3, 60), (6, 2), (7, 5), (9, 13), (14, 2)]`. I need to keep the tuples order and reenumerate second elements with integers from 0 to n - 1, where n is the list length. The result should be `[(0, 4), (1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 5), (6, 0), (7, 1), (9, 3), (14, 0)]`.

I began writing a function that accepts integer sequences, but not integer pairs:

```
def translation(seq):
    return [sorted(set(seq)).index(x) for x in seq]

>>> translate([34, 77, 6, 60, 2, 5, 13, 2])
[4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0]
```

`

Comment: Hint: when sorting a sequence of sequences, you can specify which element to sort by, using the named argument `key`.

Comment: Does it **have** to be 4, 6, 2 etc... have to be unique, or can it be any number between 0 and len(seq) - 1 ?

Comment: The given list can have second elements greater than len(seq), but the number in result must be unique unless there is a repetition. For instance, `[(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)]` should be translated to `[(1, 0), (4, 1), (12, 0)]`.

Comment: @MarcosdaSilvaSampaio If two tuples share the same second element such as (1, 8) and (12, 8) in your previous comment, should the first element be considered for the ordering?. Note that [(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)] can also be translated to [(1, 0), (4, 2), (12, 1)] since you didn't specify.

Comment: @dallen, All repeated second element must be considered. In my example: `translation([(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)]) == [(1, 0), (4, 1), (12, 0)]`.

Comment: @MarcosdaSilvaSampaio The list [(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)] ordered by the second element of every tuple can result in either [(1, 8), (12, 8), (4, 9)] or [(12, 8), (1, 8), (4, 9)] since you're not telling us wich to put first when the second element of tuples are repeated.

Comment: The initial order of tuples must be kept:
`translate([(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)]) == [(1, 0), (4, 1), (12, 0)]`, but `translate([(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)]) != [(1, 0), (12, 0), (4, 1)]` and `translate([(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)]) != [(12, 0), (1, 0), (4, 1)]`

Comment: if (1, 8) and (12, 8) should be translated to (1, 0) and (12, 0) the index method cannot be used for your translation since two elements cannot have the same index, at least not in my solution.

Comment: @MarcosdaSilvaSampaio Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I modified the code you've given so it should be easy for you to understand.

```
def translation(seq):
    return [(x[0], sorted(seq, key=lambda t: t[1]).index(x)) for x in seq]
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> translation([(0, 34), (1, 77), (2, 6), (3, 60), (6, 2), (7, 5), (9, 13)])
[(0, 4), (1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 5), (6, 0), (7, 1), (9, 3)]
```

The key parameter in sorted lets you pass a function to do the ordering, the function `lambda t: t[1]` allows for the second element of each tuple to be used for ordering.

**UPDATE**

I updated my solution so `translation([(1, 8), (4, 9), (12, 8)])` returns `[(1, 0), (4, 1), (12, 0)]`.

```
def translation(seq):
    l = list(set(sorted([x[1] for x in seq])))
    return [(x[0], l.index(x[1])) for x in seq]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
xs = [(0, 34), (1, 77), (2, 6), (3, 60), (4, 2), (5, 5), (6, 13)] 
secs = sorted(set(x[1] for x in xs))
res = [(x[0], secs.index(x[1])) for x in xs]
print res # [(0, 4), (1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 5), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 3)]
```

or one single comprehension (but with quadratic performance):

```
res = [(x[0], sum(1 for y in xs if y[1] < x[1])) for x in xs]
```